# ROS programming without physical robot

Tags: ros

I am very new to ROS and have been trying to program something for a machine which is not physically available to me yet. I would like to find some kind of virtual machine (Simulation) in which I can complete the programming and then try it on the real machine whenever available. The issue is I have just read the basics of ROS and the only simulation I could find or understand was the turtlebot. Is there any way to somehow finish the scripts for node & topics that I need? The only way I can think of atm is just write them down (as in what needs to be published, who are publishers and subscribers) and then implement it when I have the physical machine but I would appreciate if someone could guide me in a better/optimal way of doing it...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If simulating physical conditions is not as important to you, you can try [RViz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) and go through [MoveIt! tutorials](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/) to try it with simulated robots, but if you want it to represent a more realistic scenario, use Gazebo, as mentioned in the answer by BTables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more wholistic simulation environment for ROS your best bet is most likely [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_overview). ROS support is straight forward and it allows for actual simulation robotics/sensors vs. turtlebot that doesn't.

Comment: okay as I said, I am very very new to ROS. I read this book about intro to ROS by Robotis but that is all about turtlebot. So, if I have a basic structure of what I want to do and how do I want the communication to go, what would be the perfect way to start? and what would I nee? (other than a PC with ROS on it) I'd really appreciate it if you could like break it into steps somehow. I am so lost, I am sorry and thank you so much btw :)